# Update Table Storage entity using rest api with sas token says "method not allowed"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Trying to update the entity of azure table storage using api with sas token but it is showing method not allowed.

*endpoint:*
`https://{myaccount}.table.core.windows.net/{tablename}?sastoken`

*method:* PUT, Patch

Comment: Please share your complete code.

Comment: Its working now.I didn't add the partition key and rowkey in the url that's why it was not working but  working fine now.
url should be in this format
https://{myaccount}.table.core.windows.net/{tablename}(PartitionKey={'PartitionKey'},RowKey={'RowKey'})?sastoken

Comment: @DeepakSingh, you can post your comment as an answer, it would help others.

Comment: sure @IvanYang i will post it in the asnwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now.I didn't add the partition key and rowkey in the url that's why it was not working but working fine now.

The url should be in this format :

**https://{myaccount}.table.core.windows.net/{tablename}(PartitionKey={'PartitionKey'},RowKey={'RowKey'})?sastoken**

Please refer to the [update entity api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2) for more details.